# How to know if emacs is running as a daemon?

Tags: daemon, server

I want to know if emacs is running as a daemon, so I can load some parts of my configuration according, I want to know this from within emacs.

Comment: "$ ps aux" shows if there is a daemon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply use `(daemonp)` which will return `t` if emacs is running as a daemon.